# SQL select max from specified column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show data max from specified colum, is this even possible?
I am still newbie on this SQL.

I have data like this

```
Id  Order_id    Sequence
------------------------
1   A01            1
2   A01            2
3   A02            1 
4   A02            2
5   A02            3
6   A03            1
```

`Id` is the primary key.

Expected result

```
Id  Order_id    Sequence
------------------------
2   A01           2
5   A02           3
6   A03           1
```

Comment: Yep. This is fortunately in the realm of possibilities. Read about `Group By` clause.

Comment: thanks bro, how you do dat anyway

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a sub-query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.order_id, t.sequence
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT order_id, MAX(sequence) as mx
 FROM t
 GROUP BY order_id) sub
ON t.order_id = sub.order_id
WHERE t.sequence = sub.mx
```

So basically the query called sub finds the max sequence value for each order ID. Then these results are joined back the main table, which I'm calling t, so you can slap on the id.

Comment: We’d normally write that with AND instead of WHERE, but either way works I guess

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY**

```
SELECT Id,Order_id,MAX(Sequence) AS Sequence FROM table_name GROUP BY Order_id ORDER BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the id in the result, you can just do a group by... otherwise you need an inner query as the answer provided by @kbball.

```
select order_id, max(sequence)
from tablename
Group by order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `correlated subquery` as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.Sequence =
    ( SELECT max(t2.Sequence)
     FROM table1 t2
     WHERE t1.Order_id = t2.Order_id );
```

**Result:**

```
Id   Order_id   Sequence
------------------------
2    A01        2
5    A02        3
6    A03        1
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QMA67276)**